# how to use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to evaluate the limit of a definite integral?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

How to solve out this Lebesgue integral?

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 (1+nx)(1+x^2)^{-n}dx$$

My attempt: I want to use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. If I can do so, then then I can switch the limit and integral. Then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (1+nx)(1+x^2)^{-n} = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1+nx)}{(1+x^2)^{n}}$.

Use L'Hôpital's rule $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, we then get

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n * \log(1+x^2)}$$

$$=\frac{x}{\log(1+x^2)} \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$$

$$= \frac{x}{\log(1+x^2)} *0=0$$

So I guess the final answer is 0? But I don't know how to find a dominating function $g(x)$.

Comment: That really has nothing to do with Lebesgue, it’s a limit of integrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the minimal choice of the dominating function,

$$ g(x) = \sup_{n\geq 1} f_n(x) \qquad\text{for}\qquad f_n(x) = (1+nx)(1 + x^2)^{-n}, $$

is not integrable. This is because $g(x) \sim \frac{1}{ex}$ as $x \to 0^+$. The figure below demonstrates the graph of $f_n$ for $n = 1, \ldots, 100$ as well as the envelope of $f_n$'s.

[image: graph]

To find the limit, apply the substitution $x = u/\sqrt{n}$ to get

$$ \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}} \left(u + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)\left(1 + \frac{u^2}{n}\right)^{-n} \, \mathrm{d}u. $$

Using the fact that $n \mapsto (1+u^2/n)^{-n}$ is decreasing for each $u$, it follows that

$$ \left(u + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)\left(1 + \frac{u^2}{n}\right)^{-n} \leq \frac{u + 1/\sqrt{2}}{(1 + u^2/2)^2} $$

for all $n \geq 2$. Since this bound is integrable on $[0, \infty)$, by the dominated convergence theorem,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}} \left(u + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)\left(1 + \frac{u^2}{n}\right)^{-n} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(u + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)\left(1 + \frac{u^2}{n}\right)^{-n} \mathbf{1}_{[0,\sqrt{n}]}(u) \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} u e^{-u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \left[ -\frac{1}{2}e^{-u^2} \right]_{0}^{\infty}
= \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I didn't get $$ \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\sqrt{n}} \left(u + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)\left(1 + \frac{u^2}{n}\right)^{-n} \, \mathrm{d}u. $$ What I get inside is $(1+u \sqrt{n})$

Comment: @Mariana, You pick up one extra $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ from $\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: Using the fact that $n \mapsto (1+u^2/n)^{-n}$ is decreasing for each $u$,

Comment: @Mariana, It means that the sequence $g_n(u)=(1+u^2/n)^{-n}$, when it is considered as a sequence in $n$, is decreasing. In other words, we have $$g_1(u)\geq g_2(u)\geq g_3(u) \geq \ldots \geq g_n(u) \geq \ldots $$

Comment: why is this true?

Comment: @Mariana, I agree that this is the most non-trivial part of the solution. One way to verify it is to regard $n$ as real and check that $\partial g_n/\partial n < 0$. However, my favorite argument uses [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality). A version of this inequality takes the form $$1+\alpha x\leq(1+x)^{\alpha} $$ where $x \geq -1$ and $\alpha \geq 1$ are real numbers. Then plugging $x=\frac{u^2}{n+1}$ and $\alpha=\frac{n+1}{n}$, $$1+\frac{u^2}{n}\leq\left(1+\frac{u^2}{n+1}\right)^{\frac{n+1}{n}}, $$ hence we get $g_{n+1}(u)\leq g_{n}(u)$.